# How to make sure that only the user who created a post in a blog can delete or edit it asp .net MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I make sure that only the user who created a post in a blog can delete or edit it?

I.e. A user can create a blog post and can edit it at `/post/edit/{ID}`. What if a user changes the id to some other different value to a post which doesn't belong to him?

How to make sure that the post which he will edit belongs to him only?

Comment: It depends on how you track your users.  Essentially you need to add some logic in the application such that you check the identity of the logged-in user against the record they're attempting to edit.  (This assumes that you track in the data the identity of the user who created the record, naturally.)

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. Yes I track the record of who created the post.Now if he is supposed to edit a post with id 25 or 26 or 39 ,but he intentionally goes to a url /post/edit/999 .I have read your answer my question is am i supposed to create a logic in controller or model ?

Comment: It could be in the controller or the model, I suppose.  Personally I prefer the model, since authorization is a domain concern.  You could perhaps have your setters on the model check the identity of the user.  Or not use direct setters and instead have methods which accept parameters to update the model and the check the identity of the user there.  You could even go so far as to write an attribute at the class level or class member level which performs this check to avoid excessive code duplication, since it's a bit of a cross-cutting concern.

Comment: Can you give a sample code with a simple example.?

Comment: I guess the simplest example would be to check the identity of the user in the controller action.  Something like: `if (someUserObject.ID != someModelObject.CreatedByUserID) throw new Exception("User is not allowed to edit this record.");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom `Authorize` attribute in which you will query your database to ensure that the currently connected user is the author of the blog post that he is trying to modify:

```
public class EnsureAuthorOfBlogAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string blogId = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] as string;
        string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        return IsBlogAuthor(username, blogId);
    }

    private bool IsBlogAuthor(string username, string blogId)
    {
        // TODO: you know what to do here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then decorate the controller action with this custom attribute:

```
[HttpDelete]
[EnsureAuthorOfBlog]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

and same for editing:

```
[HttpPut]
[EnsureAuthorOfBlog]
public ActionResult Update(BlogViewModel blog)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @user1609429, I am glad I could help. If this answer helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.